# TheApplyAsync with CompletableFuture uses the same thread as SupplyAsync thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to Java thread, and I am trying to learn how completableFuture API works.  When I ran the code below, I get the thread name output, as shown below.  SupplyAsync and ThenApplyAsync seem to be using the same thread, which is ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1.  My understanding is that if I use ThenApplyAsync, ThenApplyAsync uses  different thread from SupplyAsync.  Can you tell me what is going on here?  Thanks!

**Code**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        System.out.println("Current Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        CompletableFuture<String> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            System.out.println("Current Thread (SupplyAsync) : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
            }
            return "Result";
        }).thenApplyAsync(result -> {
            System.out.println("Current Thread (ThenApplyAsync) : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return result.toUpperCase();
        });

        System.out.println("CompletableFuture Result : " + future.get());
    }
```

**Output:**

```
Current Thread : main
Current Thread (SupplyAsync) : ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
Current Thread (ThenApplyAsync) : ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
CompletableFuture Result : RESULT
```

Comment: Try executing multiple time you will get the different thread names and also please check how many processors available on your system `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`

Comment: The `xxxAsync` methods which do not accept an `Executor` will use the common `ForkJoinPool`. Most likely it just happens to be the same thread that executed the first stage that also picks up the second stage when it's submitted. It's also possible you only have one or two available processors and so the parallelism of the common `ForkJoinPool` is one.

Comment: Your title needs to state the problem

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong to assume that thenApplyAsync will use a different thread than the previous completion stage.

> `<U> CompletableFuture<U> thenApplyAsync(Function<? super T,? extends U> fn)`
>
> `Returns a new CompletionStage that, when this stage completes normally, is executed using this stage's default asynchronous execution facility, with this stage's result as the argument to the supplied function.`

It uses the same executionFacility as the previous stage ie, `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`. But beyond that there is no guarantee on which thread in the pool it runs on.

Comment: oh Ok.  Thank you